# Retrieving order detail on magento multiple address checkout

Tags: checkout

as i customizing my magento onepage checkout, i retrieve the data with

```
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); in my success.phtml file
```

and then disable the session by this code

```
// $session->clear(); in mage onepage controller page
```

now i am just wondering, how to retrieve it on multiple address checkout success,

actually i want to make my multiple address checkout confirmation looks like the overview page (previous page before place order)

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the success page of the multishipping checkout you can have more than one order.
You have the variable `$_orderIds` that contains those ids.
The variable is populated by this code:

```
$_orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
```

So you can use `$this->getOrderIds()`.
You can get the actual order details like this:

```
foreach ($_orderIds as $id=>$incrementId) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
    //or
    //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    //do your magic here with $order object
}
```